# Laravel Form Model binding with dynamic table rows and auto fill from db

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.2

My create form has the ability to dynamically add tr rows via jquery to insert more data into db.  How do I pull this data and auto fill my edit form using Form Model Binding (or another way).

UPDATE due to Nazmul Hasan comment:

Code Examples:

View: (Supplier hasmany relationship with supplier extras)

```
    @foreach ($supplier['SupplierExtra'] as $extra)            
        <tr class="master">
            <td>{!! Form::text('SupplierExtraName[]', $extra->name, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
            <td>{!! Form::text('SupplierExtraCost[]', $extra->cost, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
```

Controller:(store)

```
 foreach ($request->get('SupplierExtraName') as $i => $row) {
                if ($request->SupplierExtraName[$i] != null) {
                    Extra::create([
                        'supplier_id' => $supplier->id,
                        'name' => $request->SupplierExtraName[$i],
                        'cost' => $request->SupplierExtraCost[$i],
                    ]);
                }
            }
```

Controller: (update) - UNKNOWN code

How do I tell Laravel which row to update in the db?

Comment: You have to fill dynamically added row manually. You can try using foreach loop in edit mode

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand with your questions, you can try these:

### 1 Considering you have create the Model firsthand, get all that Model.

If you have not created the model, you can try:

```
php artisan make:model Example
```

For the sake of example, let's call it Example model.

Here might be its data:

```
----------------------------------------
ID       Name        Age         Phone
----------------------------------------
1        Sam         20          12345
2        Mia         23          11234
```

### 2 Pull out all the data from the controller first

```
public function functionName(Example $example){
   //We try to filter based on what your id is, say, id = 1
   //then we store that inside a variable
   $example = App\Example::where('id', '=', $example->id)->get();

   //Passing the data using compact
   return view('yourview', compact('example'));
}
```

### 3 Filling the form with your data

You need to put your data in this step, using foreach loop and putting the value using 'value' attribute inside html tag.

```
<form>
@foreach($example as $e)

    <div class="input-group">
        <h2 class="input-group">Category's Name</h2>
        <!-- the $e->Name is from the data we passed previously -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="Name" value="{{ $e->Name }}">
    </div>

@endforeach
</form>
```

Guess what will fill the text-input? That will be Sam.

The 'value' attribute inside the text-input is what you're looking far, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

So following from Nazmul Hasan comment I have the following store function in my controller

Update Controller:

```
        foreach ($request->get('SupplierExtraName') as $key => $row) {
            Extra::where('id', $key)->update([
                'name' => $request->SupplierExtraName[$key],
                'cost' => $request->SupplierExtraCost[$key],
            ]);
```

Updated view:

```
@foreach ($supplier['SupplierExtra'] as $extra)
            <tr class="master">
                <td>{!! Form::text("SupplierExtraName[$extra->id]", $extra->name, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
                <td>{!! Form::text("SupplierExtraCost[$extra->id]", $extra->cost, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md addRow">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add a row
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```